# trying to add a template file to my module using hook_theme_registry_alter

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

Here's my .module code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registery_alter()
 */
function popover_theme_registery_alter(&$theme_registery) {
    $theme_registery['popover'] = array(
        'template' => drupal_get_path('module','popover'). '/popover.tpl.php',
        'type' => 'module',
    );
}
```

I'm having some plain html elements in the tpl.php file so that might be not good? or do I have to call this hook somewhere? what's wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to declare a theme function, i.e. to be called like `$output = theme('popover', array(/* some args */));`, that uses a template file for it's output?

Comment: I want my module to output the html content instead of just putting it at the end of my module after I close php with `?>`, I want to us a template and this is my try of doing it. So I guess this only generates a renderable array? I need to Implement a function to generate the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd imagine you should be using `hook_theme()` instead of `hook_registry_alter()` to define your theme function:

```
function MYMODULE_theme() {
  return array(
    'popover' => array(
      'template' => 'popover',
      'variables' => array('var1' => array(), 'var2' => '')
    )
  );
}
```

Then you can call it from anywhere (including a page callback, which I think is where you're trying to return this from given your comment above):

```
$output = theme('popover', array('var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2));
```

In the `popover.tpl.php` file in your module's root folder you'll have access to the variables `$var1` and `$var2`, which will be the vars you defined/passed into the theme function.

Then you can build up your HTML as you need.

Comment: Thanks that seams logic I'll try that now. I won't be needing a page callback ( I think ) since it can just run when the module is enabled. But yes this is what I was looking for.